# Organize a Set of PL-sql query in Asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, plsql

i have an interface on which the user can select multiple values:

Input x:

```
   a , b , c , d .....(100 values for have an estimation )
```

Input y:

```
   aa, bb, cc, dd .... (100 values for have an estimation )
```

i have just 1 query that should change(the where condition) based on the input x and y.

For example if the user select:

```
  a,b (for x)
```

and

```
  aa,bb
```

the query should be:

```
 select * from Table where condition1 = a and condition2 = aa

 select * from Table where condition1 = b and condition2 = aa

 select * from Table where condition1 = a and condition2 = bb

 select * from Table where condition1 = b and condition2 = bb
```

so it is the cartesian product of all combinations....

so my question is how i can optimize the queries? i don't know someone told me to use NVL function

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php can you help me to put a good structure on it ? thank you

One important thing:

the user can select nothing for one of the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `condition1 in (x values list) and condition2 in (y values list)`

Try this

```
select * from Table 
where (@x is null or condition1 IN ('a','b')) 
and (@y is null or condition2 in ('aa','bb'));
```

Example:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 'a' COL1, 'aa' COL2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' COL1, 'bb' COL2 FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' COL1, 'cc' COL2 FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' COL1, 'aa' COL2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' COL1, 'bb' COL2 FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' COL1, 'cc' COL2 FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' COL1, null COL2 FROM DUAL
)

select * from cte where col1 in ('a','b') and col2 in ('aa','bb');
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11163)

Comment: sorry for the noobness can you explain me how this works ? and where is my Table name ?

Comment: @frank, that was an example, you copy that sql and modify it to include your table and columns. I updated post with sql that matches your question.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh ok it is an example that show how to use the 'In' statement

Comment: do you think that from the point of view of the performance if i have 100 x 100 values it is pretty fast In statement ?

Comment: how are you returning data now? How bad it is performance wise?

Comment: i have one more problem i did not write ..  The user can select also NOthing for one of the two Inputs

Comment: i just dont want it takes more then 1 minute

Comment: so for example in statement would works when i have no input ?

Comment: @frank check updated answer, you question is not complete and there is no clear description how you are passing parameters to pl/sql and what your current code looks like and how bad it is.

Comment: i still have not written the code i m just thinking on how to write it :)  but your answer is ok , i will ask more but for now is enough, i will try with performance on In statement